# drupal_set_message() not working in node.tpl.php template on Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-templates

My problem is with
`<?php drupal_set_message('Hello World'); ?>`

in node.tpl.php

In node.tpl.php, I have also done
        `<?php print_r(get_defined_vars()); ?>`
to find out if the theme template is set correctly. The answer is yes.

I also have page_top and page_bottom set in my [theme].info file
        `regions[content] = Content
        regions[help] = Help
        regions[page_top] = Page Top
        regions[page_bottom] = Page Bottom`

$messages is outputted in page.tpl.php
        `<div id="messages">
          <?php  print $messages; ?>
        </div>`

After checking through all these, drupal_set_message() is still not working in **node.tpl.php**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $messages variable isn't listed in the [node.tpl.php documentation for Drupal 7](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.tpl.php/7). Do you have the $page_top variable being output in your [html.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--html.tpl.php/7)? I think that may be where the messages get output in D7.

Comment: p.s. - You may also want to check out the Drupal Answers Beta site. The more people who use it, the better chance it has of making it past beta: http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hey Matt, you are right. $page_top is missing from page.tpl.php
Many thanks!
On top of that, thanks for the link too. drupal.stackexchange.com is just the perfect place for me to hang out.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 might render the messages *before* the node templates, that's why you can't see those messages.

Yes, it feels wrong to me too, and [here is a little discussion](http://drupal.org/node/1059260) and confirmation about the topic. (Closed: work as designed)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but you might be able to create a preprocess_node function and pass $messages to the node templates.

```
function template_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  $vars['messages'] = drupal_get_messages();
}
```